# Why is this question off-topic? Jeff Atwood blogged about it!

Tags: discussion

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155693/sending-mail-by-host-is-true

I'll grant you that the grammar isn't perfect, but the question speaks to a real programming (or programmer's) problem.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Often, businesses are reluctant to spend money to outsource their email operations; and so, they task one of their programmers to reduce their spam volume.

Comment: you have been here long enough to know that if its something on this site is publicized its closed for good measure

Comment: I find it a bit annoying that the question in question made it to Meta, got 2 re-open votes, still no one bothered to edit it and fix at least the obvious grammar mistakes... Not a stab at you personally Jim, a lot of other people visited the question. Anyways, in general please edit before bringing a question up on Meta, more chances re-opening if it's at its best shape possible.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Yep. That's fair.

Comment: So would the fact that Jeff Atwood blogged about [Lorem Ipsum](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/05/the-eternal-lorem-ipsum.html), [community building](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do.html), [holiday gifts](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/12/gifts-for-geeks-2011-edition.html), and [parenting](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/10/on-parenthood.html) make those things on-topic too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I closed it because:

1. It's not at all clear what the OP is asking.
2. What I *thought* it was asking was more of a business question "Do I need an e-mail marketing service?" which is off topic for this site.

If it was asking about how to design a system then it would be on topic, but at the moment - as the question currently stands - it's not a good fit at all for the site.

Comment: +1: Fair enough. FYI: I didn't write the question.

Comment: @JimG. - sorry about the incorrect attribution.